# Multiplying/duplicating/triplicating rows in SQL efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know how to efficiently (computation-wise) duplicate/triplicate/quadruple rows in a given SQL table. I know I could build a small table containing just a series of `INT` (say, from 1 to 4 to quadruple the existing rows) and use `CROSS JOIN` to do the job as below (example can also be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d0cfd/1)) --

```
CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
    ([productName] varchar(13), [description] varchar(57))
;

INSERT INTO ForgeRock
    ([productName], [description])
VALUES
    ('OpenIDM', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions'),
    ('OpenAM', 'Full-featured access management'),
    ('OpenDJ', 'Robust LDAP server for Java')
;

CREATE TABLE Multiplier (
    [Times] int
);

INSERT INTO Multiplier (Times)
VALUES 
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4)
;

SELECT
  productName,
  description
FROM
  ForgeRock
CROSS JOIN 
  Multiplier
```

but this is a bit round-about way in my opinion (because we have to build another table with integers in it) and I'm wondering if anyone has a more elegant and efficient approach (preferably using just simple SQL such as ISO 9075 compliant one).

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Please don't spam the database tags. I removed the conflicting tags, please tag only the one database you are running.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If 2022 you could also do `CROSS JOIN GENERATE_SERIES(1,3)` - I have no idea if that is "ISO 9075 compliant" but it is at least also implemented in Postgres

Comment: creating a generic numbers table PKed by number and then joining it should be most "iso" there is. Rest of stuff like cross apply, series functions etc. usually differ a bit between databases.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Thank you for sharing a way to do this in SQL Server 2022!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is the standard way to go. If you want to avoid creating a table of numbers, you can declare it within the query using a row-constructore syntax.

In SQL Server, you would use `VALUES()`:

```
SELECT f.productName, f.description
FROM ForgeRock f
CROSS JOIN ( VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4) ) v(times)
```

An alternative is to use a recursive query to duplicate the rows - but this is likely to be less efficient, especially if a large number of rows need to be duplicated:

```
with cte as (
    SELECT productName, description, 0 lvl, 4 max_lvl FROM ForgeRock
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT productName, description, lvl + 1, max_lvl FROM cte WHERE lvl < max_lvl
)
SELECT productName, description FROM cte
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Follow-up question - I assume both of the solutions you provided above aren't part of basic SQL syntax (ISO 9075), meaning they require SQL syntax specific to the flavor of SQL engine I'm using? Thank you again!

Comment: @user1330974: the most portable solution is the one you are already using. `VALUES`  is not supported in all databases (but they all have alternatives), and the syntax of recursive queries slightly varies across databases.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply! I'll accept your response as answer.